# Objective-C & C++ interface GSCBufferString to string

Tags: c++, objective-c, json

I am writing an Objective-C wrapper for a C++ class. On the OC side I have to take an `NSData` (read from a json file) get a list out from it and convert that to `std::vector< std::string >`. Here is my code so far (in an `mm` file):

```
NSData *input = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"1455469592904_acceldata742283.json"]];    
NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:input options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *accdata = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"data.accelerometer" ];
    int size = [accdata count];
    vector<string> cppAccdata;
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
        //~ cppAccdata.push_back();
        NSLog(@"%@",[accdata objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
```

The `accdata` speaking loosely is a list of strings. The json file basically looks like this (with more lines but that's beside the point):

```
{
  "data" : {
    "accelerometer" : [
      "1455463005.714     -8.311620700836182     -3.969735990142822     -3.737648066711425",
      "1455463005.724     -8.256703700256347     -4.017769660949707     -3.680336864471435" ] }}
```

The output of the code is:

```
2016-02-15 14:18:16.212 test-OC[10300] 1455463066.241     -7.960421244812011     -4.400093738555908     -3.746177410125732
2016-02-15 14:18:16.212 test-OC[10300] 1455463066.261     -8.019677735900878     -4.377498460388184     -3.634847032928467
2016-02-15 14:18:16.212 test-OC[10300] GSCBufferString
```

Technically I need to convert `[accdata objectAtIndex:i]` to an std::string, which I guess would work through a C `const char *`, but I have not been able to find anything on converting a `GSCBufferString` into anything. How can I achieve this? There also might be a more elegant way to loop through `accdata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two answer proposed were correct in the way of doing the conversion, but the loop syntax didn't compile. This workaround works though:

```
int size = [accdata count];
vector<string> cppAccdata;
for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
    cppAccdata.push_back([[accdata objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *accdata = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"data.accelerometer" ];
vector<string> cppAccdata;
for (NSString *str in accdata) {
    cppAccdata.push_back(str.UTF8String);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this gives me a compile error (I don't understand why, this type of looping works in an m file but not in an mm)
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘in’
     for (NSString *str in accdata) {

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *jsonArray;
NSArray *accData = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"data.accelerometer"];
vector<string> cppAccdata;
for (NSString *str in accData){
    std::string *accString = new std::string([str UTF8String]);
    cppAccdata.push_back(*accString);

}
```

Comment: I get compiler errors: `expected ‘;’ before ‘in’` and `error: ‘in’ was not declared in this scope`. Same as the other answer, it doesn't seem to like this syntax.

Comment: `std::string` memory leak. It's `C++`s class, it doesn't have ARC.